# Connection through telnet only works in safe mode

Tags: macos, network

I'm running Xamarin's iOS Build Host app on my machine. It uses telnet on port 5000 to allow connections to it. Suddenly, this connection no longer works.

```
telnet localhost 5000
HELO
```

returns nothing.

However if I boot my Mavericks into safe mode and do the same, I first get a question if "mtbserver" should allow incoming connections. Afterwards, the telnet connection succeeds.

Back in normal mode, I have already tried to disable the firewall but without success.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had AirServer installier which uses port 5000. It won't be started in safe mode.